# SharePoint list validation code not working

Tags: validation-list-items, column-validation

[image]I have a requirement, if a user chooses 'Copy' from a drop down an additional field needs content, and if the user choose 'No-Copy' then the additional field CAN be blank.

Here is my script and when it runs it works fine, but if 'No-copy' is selected afterwards the change does not happen in the list. So I believe its my script that is at fault.

```
=IF(TAtestColumnChoose="Copy",IF(ISBLANK(Description),FALSE,TRUE),FALSE)
```

any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the formula value to `TRUE` in case user selects the "No-Copy". So, try using below formula:

```
=IF([TAtestColumnChoose]="Copy",IF(ISBLANK([Description]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

**Note:**

1. Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).

Comment: Try this and let me know it works or not.

Comment: it works once as No-Copy, then as Copy, and then when I change It back again the column does not change on the list.

Comment: I have added a picture where can see on the edit screen its one value and on the list its another.

Comment: any ideas anyone ?

Comment: even with the simplest validation it does not work - such as : =OR(TAtestColumnChoose="Copy",TAtestColumnChoose="No-Copy")

Comment: Is there any column level validation added on any field?

Comment: not at all, this is very strange

Comment: I have got it working but only when you select the row and press the I button near the filter on the right hand side. There has to be something wrong with changing a column value all the time within SharePoint..  unless you can think of anything else ?

Comment: UPDATE : If I put the list into classic mode then it works and the column updates all the time on the list... is there any reason for this ? If you set the list as modern you maybe able to update the column 3 times one after another.